# Is it possible to register metric on Job Manager in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to expose information to our monitoring system about currently running job version on k8s. For now, simple metric exposed on Job Manager would suffice. Is it possible to register such metric in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to register custom metrics on the `JobManager`. Instead what you could do it to register a custom metric in one of your UDFs:

```java
new RichMapFunction<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        if (getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask() == 0) {
            getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().gauge("version", (Gauge<String>) () -> MY_VERSION_STRING);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer map(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        return integer;
    }
}
```

This will register the metric `version` under `<host>.taskmanager.<tm_id>.<job_name>.<operator_name>.0.version`.